# Manipulate Date, new day starts at specific time SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I'm developping a dashboard for a restaurant/bar.

I want to manipulate the date , so for example:

If they sell something at 02 january ,01h30 . 
This amount should be added to the amount of the 1st January and not to the amount of the 2nd January.
So basically on the next day from 00h00 until 03h59, the amount that they sell, should be added to the previous date.

At the moment my SQL query just displays both dates but I want it grouped in 1 date. If this isn't possible with SQL, I have my dashboard in PHP, so I can eventually manipulate it in PHP if anyone could provide me that info.

My query

```
select CONVERT(CHAR(10), receiptdatetime, 120), datename(DW,receiptdatetime),
sum(rld.NetAmount), count(rl.ReceiptId) 
from receipt r, receiptline rl, vw_ReceiptLineDetail rld 
where rl.ReceiptId = r.ReceiptId and 
rl.ModifiedKind != 300 
and rld.ReceiptLineId = rl.ReceiptLineId and 
receiptdatetime <= DATEADD(HOUR,4,DATEADD(DAY,1, '01/01/2018')) 
and  receiptdatetime >= DATEADD(HOUR,4,'01/01/2018') 
group by CONVERT(CHAR(10), receiptdatetime, 120), datename(DW, receiptdatetime) 
order by 1
```

So the current output is like this (shortened):

```
   Date           Amount
1  01/01/2018      100
2  02/01/2018      20
```

But I want it like this

```
   Date           Amount
1  01/01/2018      120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query and work with dates as you want

here is you first query that gives you that result

```
select CONVERT(CHAR(10), receiptdatetime, 120), datename(DW,receiptdatetime),
        sum(rld.NetAmount), count(rl.ReceiptId) 
        from receipt r, receiptline rl, vw_ReceiptLineDetail rld 
        where rl.ReceiptId = r.ReceiptId and 
        rl.ModifiedKind != 300 
        and rld.ReceiptLineId = rl.ReceiptLineId and 
        receiptdatetime <= DATEADD(HOUR,4,DATEADD(DAY,1, '01/01/2018')) 
        and  receiptdatetime >= DATEADD(HOUR,4,'01/01/2018') 
        group by CONVERT(CHAR(10), receiptdatetime, 120), datename(DW, receiptdatetime) 
        order by 1
```

you can use this result as a first select with this :

```
With CTE as 

(
        select CONVERT(CHAR(10), receiptdatetime, 120), datename(DW,receiptdatetime),
        sum(rld.NetAmount), count(rl.ReceiptId) 
        from receipt r, receiptline rl, vw_ReceiptLineDetail rld 
        where rl.ReceiptId = r.ReceiptId and 
        rl.ModifiedKind != 300 
        and rld.ReceiptLineId = rl.ReceiptLineId and 
        receiptdatetime <= DATEADD(HOUR,4,DATEADD(DAY,1, '01/01/2018')) 
        and  receiptdatetime >= DATEADD(HOUR,4,'01/01/2018') 
        group by CONVERT(CHAR(10), receiptdatetime, 120), datename(DW, receiptdatetime) 
        order by 1
)
```

so like this you have the result stored on a table called CTE 
NOw i don't have the data so i will create my owne Variable table to store the result that you got from first query you can use your CTE tabale as a source instade of @Table

```
Declare @Table table (
    id int,
    dates date,
    amout int
)

insert into @Table
select 1 ,   '2018-01-01' , 100 union 
select 2 ,   '2018-01-02' , 20 union
select 2 ,   '2018-02-02' , 200 union 
select 2 ,   '2018-01-03' , 20 union 
select 2 ,   '2018-01-04' , 20
```

now to get the Amout with the result that you want here is the query to use 
you do the select from CTE :

```
select sum(amout) as Amout  from @Table
where dates between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-04'
```

---

```
Result : 

Amout
160
```

now you will use that result and union it with you table to get the ID that you want and the date that you want and i thing you should convert the last table date into nvarchar(50) so you will have this result

1- when you do the whole month

```
ID     Date     Amout
1     2018-01    160
```

2- when you do by timeframe

```
ID            Date                   Amout
1     '2018-01-01 2018-01-14'         160
```

you can start by hardcoding the ID and Date as you want and union is to the result Amout that you get from the query 
or you can do variables to configure the ID and date that you want to show with the Amout

thanks if you ahve any questions i'm here i have done the test on my local and it works and i hope that this is what you need :)

[image]

Comment: You cna also store the First Query Result into a Temp DB or a variable DB if you want insted of using the CTE table to be more clear when you will debug if needed

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination ! Works as it should !

Answer (score 0):

use the :

```
;With CTE as ( select (RowCount() Over (Partition by Date order by id) row_count) , date, amout 
from tables and where conditions
```

Then on the select Add the amount that have the same Date into each others 
selecting from CTE table

if you want to Add the Amounts of all day on the same month then select Only Year and Month on Date column then do the partition by over this Date

Comment: Will test this asap, will this also works when I do a select a timeframe of a week?

Comment: Yes it will i will fo you a simple exp on the secend answare